# AngularJS is not a function error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a payment system in my e-commerce web application where I need installment options to be chosen by the client. I use angularjs to get that information but I get the error that all the provided functions below are not functions. I can provide additional information, but here is the part related to the issue:

```
$scope.tekcekim() = function () {
        $scope.strInstallmentCount = "";
    };

    $scope.taksit2() = function () {
        $scope.strInstallmentCount = "2";
    };

    $scope.taksit3() = function () {
        $scope.strInstallmentCount = "3";
    };
```

Comment: $scope.tekcekim() to $scope.tekcekim
 $scope.taksit2() to  $scope.taksit2

Comment: $scope.taksit3() to $scope.taksit3

Answer (score 2):

remove () in your $scope.

```
$scope.tekcekim = function () {
        $scope.strInstallmentCount = "";
    };

    $scope.taksit2 = function () {
        $scope.strInstallmentCount = "2";
    };

    $scope.taksit3 = function () {
        $scope.strInstallmentCount = "3";
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be without **`()`** ,

```
$scope.tekcekim = function () {
        $scope.strInstallmentCount = "";
};

$scope.taksit2 = function () {
    $scope.strInstallmentCount = "2";
};

$scope.taksit3 = function () {
    $scope.strInstallmentCount = "3";
};
```

Comment: I will need to clean my glasses to see the difference though

Comment: @NebihBaşaran just remove the braces next to variable names

Comment: mark if it helped

Answer (score 0):

remove () paranthesis.  write any function with $scope like ex shown below

> ```
>  $scope.foo=function(){   
>          //some code goes here 
>    };
> ```